# Determining number separator when inputHidden doesn't format a currency number

Tags: javascript, controller, formatting, locale

If I return an object with a currency field, and I'm returning it from a controller. If I use an `<apex:inputField>`, the number is correctly formatted as `1,234.56`.

However, if I use an `<apex:inputHidden>`, then the number will be returned as `1234.56` (without a thousand separator). I'd like to use that number to determine the current decimal separator dynamically (Javascript is used to perform some calculations).

Can I force the `<apex:inputHidden>` to format the number? Alternatively, how can I determine the current user's local settings for number separators in a controller? `UserInfo.getLocale` will get the locale. Is there an equivalent of `DecimalFormat` for Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `apex:inputHidden`, why don't you just use `<span style="display: none"><apex:outputField id="someId" value="{!someRecord.CurrencyField__c}"/></span>`? This way, the user won't see it, but you'll still get your formatting preferences.